# Profiling neo4j query: filter to db hits

Tags: neo4j

I'm curious how filters work in neo4j queries. They result in db hits (according to PROFILE), and it seems that they shouldn't.

An example query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (a:act)<-[r:relationship]-(n)
WHERE a.chapter='13' and a.year='2009'
RETURN r, n
```

1. NodeIndexSeek: (I created the an index on the label `act` for `chapter` property) returns 6 rows.
2. Filter:  `a.year == {AUTOSTRING1}` which results in 12 db hits.

Why does it need to do any db hits if it's already fetched the 6 matching instances of `a` in earlier db reads, shouldn't it just filter them down without going back to do more db reads?

I realise I'm equating 'db hits' with 'db reads' here, which may not be accurate. If not, what exactly are 'db hits'?

Lastly, the number of db hits incurred by a filter appear to approximately match:

```
<number of filtering elements> * 2 * <number of already queried nodes to filter on>
```

where 'number of filtering elements' is the number of filters provided, i.e.

```
WHERE a.year='2009' and a.property_x='thing'
```

is two elements.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
Here are the results of PROFILE and EXPLAIN on the query.
This is just an example query. I've found the behaviour of

```
filter db hits = <number of filtering elements> * 2 * <number of already queried nodes to filter on>
```

to be generally true in queries I've run.

> PROFILE MATCH (a:act)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(n)
>   WHERE a.chapter='13' AND a.year='2009'
>   RETURN r, n

```
8 rows
55 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection
  |
  +Expand(All)
    |
    +Filter
      |
      +NodeIndexSeek

+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
|      Operator | EstimatedRows | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                     Other |
+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------------+
|    Projection |             1 |    8 |      0 |     a, n, r |                      r; n |
|   Expand(All) |             1 |    8 |      9 |     a, n, r |     (a)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(n) |
|        Filter |             0 |    1 |     12 |           a | a.year == {  AUTOSTRING1} |
| NodeIndexSeek |             1 |    6 |      7 |           a |             :act(chapter) |
+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------------------+

Total database accesses: 28
```

> EXPLAIN MATCH (a:act)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(n)
>   WHERE a.chapter='13' AND a.year='2009'
>   RETURN r, n

```
4 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

Projection
  |
  +Expand(All)
    |
    +Filter
      |
      +NodeIndexSeek

+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+
|      Operator | EstimatedRows | Identifiers |                     Other |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+
|    Projection |             1 |     a, n, r |                      r; n |
|   Expand(All) |             1 |     a, n, r |     (a)<-[r:CHILD_OF]-(n) |
|        Filter |             0 |           a | a.year == {  AUTOSTRING1} |
| NodeIndexSeek |             1 |           a |             :act(chapter) |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Because reading a node (record) and reading property (records) is not the same db-operation.

You are right that the filter hit's should be at most 6 though.
Usually Neo4j pulls filters and predicates to the earliest possible moment, so it should filter directly after the index lookup.

In some situations though (due to the predicate) it can only filter after finding the paths, then the number of db-hits might equal the number of checked paths.

Which Neo4j version are you using? Can you share your full query plan?

Comment: By query plan I assume you mean PROFILE & EXPLAIN? I've added those to my post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: > You are right that the filter hit's should be at most 6 though.
<br>
It looks like there's a DB read for every node property used in the filter, so in my example above it reads each node once for year comparison, and once for chapter comparison. If I didn't have an index on chapter, would that be the expected behaviour?